# Word: How to replace a single space separated by any number and any letter?

Tags: replace, ms-word, wildcard

I have a file of statistics which has got slightly muddled. In order to fix it I need to be able to replace any single space that has any number on its left and any letter on its right with another character, for example ¬.

So 765 apples would become 795¬apples, but orange 26 would remain unchanged.

I have loaded the file into MS Word and am trying to use the replace feature and wild cards.

Unfortunately my attempts eg ([0-9])( {1})([A-Za_z]) have failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to do this with a script/program or in MS Word only?

Comment: Maybe [`([0-9]+)( )([A-Za-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bQlter/1)

Comment: Hi, I am using the Word replace function - can't use macros they are disabled. Sorry ([0-9]+)( )([A-Za-z]+) does not work. 0 replacements. ([0-9])( )([A-Za-z]) - my mod of The fourth birds suggestion, replaces the number to the left of the space and the char to the right. So 1567 apple becomes 156¬pple. Still no good.

Comment: Have you looked at using a text editor?